# Which way could be faster to do multiplying in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to find a faster way to multiply each number in array by each to find a pair which multiplication result would be the same as sum of numbers in that array excluded that pair.

e.g.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And result should be [(6, 7), (7, 6)] because sum of array without 6 and 7 is 42 so the same as their multiplication.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using two for loops in the same array but this method is definitely too slow

Comment: can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Suggest you read up on the topic of [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I guess any simple approach is going to be **O**(_n^2_).  Having worked out how to solve the problem by working through all the possible combinations, you need to try to find ways to eliminate some (most ?) of them.

Comment: @ChrisHall Nah, not any simple approach is O(n^2), as can be seen by the accepted(!) answer :-)

Comment: @HeapOverflow: so `permutations()` is not O(n^2) ?  And `sum()` is not then O(n) for every possible permutation ?  Or are you telling me this is worse than O(n^2) ?

Comment: @ChrisHall Yes, *not* being O(n^2) means being *worse* than O(n^2). Just like something not being affordable with $100 means it costs *more*.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: fair enough, I should have said "at least O(n^2)".  To be honest, O(n^2) scares the living daylights out of me, so I didn't think any deeper about it than that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in just one line using `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

[(i,j) for i,j in permutations(arr, 2) if sum(arr)-i-j == i*j]
```

the out put will be:

```
Out[1]: [(6, 7), (7, 6)]
```

the fastest way is to use built-in libraries in python like `itertools`.

Comment: `combination` rather than `permutation` ?  Since the array is sorted, you can stop before doing 6*8 (since 6*8 > 55-6-8).  Since the sum is odd, you could avoid all the even * even ?  Also there's not much point doing any combination with a multiplier of 4 or less (since 4*9 < 55-4-9).

Comment: You are right..

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's curious, I benchmarked 3 brute-force solutions, including Mehrdad's.

```
def benchmark(iterations, func, *args):
    from time import perf_counter
    from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    from os import devnull
    with redirect_stdout(open(devnull, "w")):
        start_time = perf_counter()
        for i in range(iterations):
            func(*args)
        total_time = perf_counter() - start_time
    print(f"{total_time} seconds for {iterations} calls to {func.__name__}")

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def typical_nested_loop():
    matches = []
    for i in arr:
        for j in arr:
            if i*j == sum(arr) - i - j:
                matches.append((i, j))
    return matches

def list_comprehension():
    return [(i, j) for i in arr for j in arr if i*j == sum(arr) - i - j]

from itertools import permutations
def list_comprehension_permutations():
    return [(i,j) for i,j in permutations(arr, 2) if sum(arr)-i-j == i*j]

benchmark(100_000, typical_nested_loop)
benchmark(100_000, list_comprehension)
benchmark(100_000, list_comprehension_permutations)
```

Results:

```
2.4516644999966957 seconds for 100000 calls to typical_nested_loop
2.3809948000125587 seconds for 100000 calls to list_comprehension
2.3246280000021216 seconds for 100000 calls to list_comprehension_permutations
```

**Update:**

Here the call to `sum(arr)` was removed from the loop, as suggested by *Heap Overflow*, which provides a huge speedup:

```
def sum_outside_loop():
    matches = []
    sum1 = sum(arr)
    for i in arr:
        sum2 = sum1 - i
        for j in arr:
            if i*j == sum2 - j:
                matches.append((i, j))
    return matches

def sum_outside_perm_comprehension():
    sum1 = sum(arr)
    return [(i,j) for i,j in permutations(arr, 2) if sum1-i-j == i*j]
```

Results:

```
2.559465099999997 seconds for 100000 calls to typical_nested_loop
2.436041499999998 seconds for 100000 calls to list_comprehension
2.356287599999998 seconds for 100000 calls to list_comprehension_permutations
0.629711299999996 seconds for 100000 calls to sum_outside_loop
0.788010899999996 seconds for 100000 calls to sum_outside_perm_comprehension
```

Comment: Probably much of the time is spent on `sum(arr)`. What are the times if you compute that once at the start and store it in a variable?

Comment: Good point! You are absolutely right. It's ~3-4x faster. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Nice, that's a larger improvement than it was for me. Of course the real improvement would come for larger arrays, where the O(n^3) vs O(n^2) would make a bigger difference. I also have an O(n log n) solution, but since the OP is so happy with an O(n^3) solution...

Comment: Cool. Can you post it here in the comments, since the question is now closed?

Comment: Sort the array, then start with indexes i=0 and j=n-1. Move i right or j left depending on whether arr[i] and arr[j] are too small or too large.

Comment: Oh and now I have an O(n) solution as well :-). If you want `i*j==sum-i-j`, then just try all `i`, for each `i` compute the needed `j`, and check whether you have that `j` in O(1) (with a set prepared at the start).